# @paypal/react-paypal-js - Getting INVALID_RESOURCE_ID error

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-buttons

I'm integrating Paypal into an application and I'm using the @paypal/react-paypal-js package. I first first create an order on the backend (route: /create-paypal-order) and then capture the payment on another route (route: /capture-paypal-payment). When I test over Postman/Swagger and programmatically submitting a form I have in the application over a custom button, everything works, the entire process goes smoothly and I can see the funds transferred in the sandbox accounts. However, when I include the PayPalScriptProvider and the PayPal button from the library, the moment I click on the button I get the error 'INVALID_RESOURCE_ID' and a really long stack trace. Now I know that the client-id has to be correct, I've tested it, so I assume the problem is somewhere in my component.

This is the script provider that wraps the App (I've provided a dummy client-id here):

```
<PayPalScriptProvider
            options={{
                'client-id': 'Cg132XmuWDL0ugY_liC8FCfQCwbcjS93SrftdEPIUvnVoVDMIf_ZyZ2tTmHgU11bpLx6wjPz8hV3t2rJ',
            }}
        >
       <AppContainer>
          <App />
        </AppContainer>
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

This is the PayPal button:

```
<PayPalButtons
     style={{ color: 'blue', height: 55, layout: 'horizontal' }}
     createOrder={createPaypalOrder}
     onApprove={capturePaypalPayment}
 />
```

This is the createPaypalOrder function (shortened only to include relevant code - I assume I don't even need the data/actions arguments if I'm calling the backend? if true, I couldn't find that piece of information anywhere online):

```
const createPaypalOrder = async (data: CreateOrderData, actions: CreateOrderActions) => {
        const response = await subscriptionService.createPaypalOrder(order);  
        setPaypalOrderId(response.result.id);
        return response.result.id
}
```

And the capturePaypalPayment function - which never even gets executed because the previous function throws the INVALID_RESOURCE_ID error:

```
const capturePaypalPayment = async (data: OnApproveData, actions: OnApproveActions) => {
            const response = await subscriptionService.capturePaypalPayment(paypalOrderId); 
    };
```

Just to reiterate once more, everything works when I, for instance, create a button of my own, put an onClick on it, call the first function when the button is clicked, open a popup window for the sandbox user to approve the payment and then capture the payment. The reason I'm not using that approach is because there is no way for me to know exactly when the user has approved the purchase (the dummy implementation just uses a 30sec timeout before the second request). But the paypal button implementation fails instantly.

If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

(On a different note, I just want to say I've tried to implement a different approach using the React example from the Paypal docs, but that doesn't even compile because I can't access the driver in the window.paypal.Buttons object.)

EDIT:
This is what the response I get from the backend for the /create-paypal-order route looks like:

```
{
  "result": {
    "id": "5NP82422M70278020",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5NP82422M70278020",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5NP82422M70278020",
        "rel": "approve",
        "method": "GET"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5NP82422M70278020",
        "rel": "update",
        "method": "PATCH"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5NP82422M70278020/capture",
        "rel": "capture",
        "method": "POST"
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": []
```

EDIT 2:

[Image of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UnKK.png)

Comment: `const response = await subscriptionService.createPaypalOrder(order);` show the contents of response (result/body).  Was the order created with the same client-id as the script is loaded with?

Comment: I've included the response in the post. As for the question, I'm certain that the client-id is the same as the client-id on the backend because I've personally inserted both.

Comment: The only odd thing I see is whatever is in the AppContainer / App could be overriding with their own PayPalScriptProvider and default client-id somehow. Use the browser network tab to confim JS is loading only with the correct client-id , and that the response from /create-paypal-order is being fetched correctly exactly after the button is clicked on

Comment: if that's not enough, console.log `response.result.id` immediately before returning it to confirm, and test hardcoding that return value as well as your client-id for script load in https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Alright, I'll try doing the things you've listed when I go back to work in a couple of days and report what happens.

Comment: Alright, I've checked and the JS does load with the correct client ID, and hardcoding the values on the paypal site works. However, I cannot console.log the response before returning it, because clicking the button instantly throws an error, no call is made to the backend at all. I've included the errors I get in an image above.

Comment: Per the top of that log the request is failing with a 400 code, so something about it is wrong/different. It is not returning the data of your first edit.  When the call to the backend fails or does not contain an `id` in the expected place, INVALID_RESOURCE_ID is the expected behavior for the JS SDK to throw.

Comment: Essentially you need to debug the code at `response = await subscriptionService.createPaypalOrder(order);  ` and whatever it calls, something has already gone wrong in there and what it sends/gets back from the server

Comment: Alright, so I've finally solved it and I cannot believe that these two things are literally not the first two things mentioned when using paypal with react:
1 You can't access the order ID from the state like I do above, instead the order ID needs to be retrieved in the onApprove function from the data object (whose type is OnApproveData).
2 Paypal doesn't rerender the onApprove and createOrder functions when state changes, meaning the data passed to it will always be the default state (in my case empty strings). You HAVE TO set forceRerender with an array of dependencies on the button.

Comment: No, forceReRender does not normally need to be used that way, you are doing something unusual. Normal pattern is that when the buttons are clicked, the callback functions are called, and retrieve and order ID from the backend, with no re-render. Normal usage pattern is to only rerender when script query configuration parameters change. This does NOT include amount. It DOES include currency, client-id, and intent, since those affect which buttons can be presented.